# db:seed laravel 5.5.x not increment sequence id of postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.5.20 and PostgreSQL 9.5.10. When I run `php artisan db:seed` then data inserted into the table but not increase the sequence id or number. Then when I try to insert the data into the table from my application then it creates an error. *Autoincrement primary id have already existed.*

How I can increment the sequence when inserting data by running `php artisan db:seed`.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this also.  Go into your seeds and check and see if you have assigned a value to the incrementing column.  If so, remove it.

Seems like when you explicitly assign a value to the incrementing column that it does not register this in the next sequence.  By leaving it out, everything works properly.